# kernel density estimation

Tags: export, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to compute CDF of historical data ( weekly change in CDS spread) using kernel density estimation. The original data has 300 observation. I uploaded data from excel

```
 '(citi = Import["CorrelD.xlsx", {"Data", "data", All, 1}]'
```

CDF is computed using below function

```
 'd = SmoothKernelDistribution[citi]
```

I can see the CDF graph computed as expected. How can I get the CDF data out in excel please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simulate data

```
data = RandomVariate[PowerDistribution[1, 2.5], 10^3];
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
Plot[CDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Export Data

```
Export["cdf.xls", Table[{x, CDF[dist, x]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]];
```

[image]